# listen for changes in value to automatically update value of another variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

if I have `foo = 1` and `bar = foo + 1`, how would I go about setting up a listener for changes in foo so that bar automatically updates when the value of foo changes?

Comment: There was [`Object.watch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) some time ago

Comment: How does foo change? Does it come from a databese? Or is it bound to a Dom element? There must be a reason why foo changes. Why don't you listen to that?

Comment: But if you want to detect when an non-object changes, I don't believe there is a way of doing that. Well, actually if it's still a property of `window`, then maybe you could...

Comment: both `foo` and `bar` would be primitives and `foo` would be updated through a click event on the DOM.  I currently have it setup so that the function that updates `foo` also updates `bar` by repeating `bar = foo + 1` through reassignment.  I wasn't sure if something like Rxjs would be appropriate for this use-case.  I'm also open to refactor these variables to be properties of an object if that makes what I'm describing more feasible.